# Form only works sometimes (PHP mySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms, post

i googled quite alot and can't really find an anwer to my problem. i created a form to submit some information on my website. the problem is it only works sometimes and i have no idea why. your help would be really appericated, im going crazy here.

PHP

```
 <?php 
require_once("php/verbindung.php");

$partyskill = "";
$partyskill2 = "";
$partylang = "";
$partycount = "";
$drop = "";

$error_count = "";
$error_lang = "";

$freigabe = true;   

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        $partyskill = "$_POST[skill]";
        $partyskill2 = "$_POST[skill2]";
        $partylang = "$_POST[language]";
        $partycount = "$_POST[count]";


        if (strlen($partycount) == 0) { 
            $error_count = "<FONT COLOR='#d1a200'>*please select how many players you are looking for</font>"; 
            $freigabe = false; 
        }

     if (strlen($partylang) == 1) {
                     if($partylang=="1")
                      {$drop="gb.png";}

                     elseif($partylang== "2")
                      {$drop="de.png";}

                     elseif($partylang== "3")
                      {$drop="ru.png";}                                     

                      else {
                       $error_lang = "<FONT COLOR='#d1a200'>*please select a language</font>";
                       $freigabe = false;
                                }
                        }

                      else {
                       $error_lang = "<FONT COLOR='#d1a200'>*please select a language</font>";
                       $freigabe = false;
                        }

        if ($freigabe == true) { 
            $sql = "INSERT INTO ".$tblparty; 
            $sql .= " (skill, skill2, count, language) 
            VALUES ("; 
            $sql .= "'".$partyskill."', "; 
            $sql .= "'".$partyskill2."', "; 
            $sql .= "'".$partycount."', ";
            $sql .= "'".$drop."') "; 

            $query = mysql_query($sql, $verb);

        }                           
}
```

?>

HTML

```
 <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" name="new_party" >
        <h3>How many players are you searching for?</h3>
            <p>
                <input type="radio" name="count" value="1"> 1
                <input type="radio" name="count" value="2"> 2
                <input type="radio" name="count" value="3"> 3
                <input type="radio" name="count" value="4"> 4
            </p>
            <?php echo $error_count; ?><br/>
        <h3>What is you prefered language?</h3>
            <p>
                <input type="radio" name="language" value="1"><img src="images/flags/gb.png"/>
                <input type="radio" name="language" value="2"><img src="images/flags/de.png"/>
                <input type="radio" name="language" value="3"><img src="images/flags/ru.png"/>
            </p>
                <?php echo $error_lang; ?><br/>
        <h3>What skill are you looking for?</h3>
            from:
            <select name="skill">
                <option value="15">Eagle Master</option>
                <option value="16">Legendary Eagle Master</option>
                <option value="17">Supreme Master First Class</option>
                <option value="18">Global Elite</option>
            </select>
            to:
            <select name="skill2">
                <option value="15">Eagle Master</option>
                <option value="16">Legendary Eagle Master</option>
                <option value="17">Supreme Master First Class</option>
                <option value="18">Global Elite</option>
            </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Send" name="submit"/>
        </form>
```

Comment: Remove the double quotes for `$partyskill = "$_POST[skill]";` and do the same for the others. Then do `$partyskill = $_POST['skill'];` etc etc. etc.

Comment: `"$_POST[skill]"`? cargo cult programming detected... exactly **HOW** does this "not work" when it's not working? Error messages? Ignores the submission? Fires off a nastygram to your mother? You also have a gaping wide-open SQL injection attack vulnerability.

Comment: @MarcB no error message given. it just sometimes gets into the database sometimes not. yes i know that this code is open to mysql incetions. is it enough to strip every input field with stripslashes etc? and can hidden input fields also be inceted?

Comment: You're welcome. However, I did test your code, and they did echo out for me (strangely enough). However, I never use the method you're presently using. Try that and see if it makes a difference or not. @user3342340 - Yet, MySQL might not like it the way you have it now.

Comment: Something else I noticed, `$tblparty` isn't defined anywhere else. Where is it coming from? @user3342340 and try doing your query like this instead `$sql = "INSERT INTO $tblparty (skill, skill2, count, language) 
VALUES ('".$partyskill."', '".$partyskill2."', '".$partycount."', '".$drop."')";`

Comment: @Fred-ii- it is defined in the verbindung(connection).php, sorryi didnt mention that.

Comment: Ok. And did you my query suggestion? @user3342340

Comment: @Fred-ii- is just tested abit and noticed it only does not work if the value from the the skill column is already the same in another row in the databse. to make it clear, it does not let me post a value twice in the database, for the same colum, even if it is a different row. does anybody know why?

Comment: @Fred-ii- jup, changed it and its working fine :) but i still have the problem with the same values.

Comment: If one of your columns is set to `AUTO_INCREMENT` or has a foreign key, it won't let you. @user3342340 also double check your column names and the variables if the match.

Comment: @Fred-ii- no auto increment or foreign key :/ skill column is type"INT" with a lenght"2" he rest is blank or standard. hope this helps.

Comment: Then try removing the quotes around `$partyskill` and try `$sql = "INSERT INTO $tblparty (skill, skill2, count, language) 
VALUES ($partyskill, '".$partyskill2."', '".$partycount."', '".$drop."')";` also try to increase your `int` to `5` to test.

Comment: @Fred-ii- tried it, still the same problem. the strange is the column skill2 is handled exactly the same way and it works just fine there :/

Comment: Then, try putting backticks `\`` around your column names in `(skill, skill2, count, language)` other than that, I don't know what it could be. Did you also change to `$partyskill = $_POST['skill'];` ?

Comment: @Fred-ii- did not work either. can i just change the colum to VARCHAR?

Comment: Yes you can try changing it to that.

Comment: @Fred-ii- didnt help either. BUT i got it now. i delted the colum "skill" in the database an create it again (exactly the same) and it works now. i have no idea why but im glad.  thank you sir, you were a big help. may i invite you to a low priced steam game(~5€)?

Comment: That's great news! Thanks but I'm not a gamer. One thing I could do though, is post an answer with a few of my suggestions, and you can accept as being correct.

Comment: Ok. Let me know if there's something you wish for me to change in my answer also.

Comment: I added some important notes at the bottom of my answer. Reload it to see the additions.

Comment: @Fred-ii- ill try to read abit into this pdo thing, we learned it like this in school, it sucks to hear its outdated since forever :| thanks alot fred, you were great help :)

Comment: It's worth learning, because the old functions are dangerous to use. You're very much welcome, I was glad to help and that a solution was found :) Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO ".$tblparty; 
$sql .= " (skill, skill2, count, language) 
VALUES ("; 
$sql .= "'".$partyskill."', "; 
$sql .= "'".$partyskill2."', "; 
$sql .= "'".$partycount."', ";
$sql .= "'".$drop."') ";
```

Change it to:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `$tblparty` (`skill`, `skill2`, `count`, `language`) 
VALUES ('".$partyskill."', '".$partyskill2."', '".$partycount."', '".$drop."')";
```

then delete your `skill` column and re-create it again. You could also attempt to rebuild your table.

Also, I suggest that you switch to [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/mysqli) functions using [`prepared statements`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [**PDO**](http://www.php.net/PDO), `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and will be deleted in future releases.